# Can't drop index column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have read all of the relevant questions posted here and none of the solutions work. I have tried:

```
1 - df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
2 - df.to_csv(path, index=False)
3 - df.read_csv(path, index_col=False)
```

None of the above work.

Comment: It will be hard debugging your problem without a sample of your dataset and your (full) code.

Answer (score 0):

seems fine to me...

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({"t":[1,2,3]},index=[5,6,7])

print(df)

df2 = df.reset_index(drop=True)

print(df2)
print(df)

df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
print(df)
```